# Struct is changing values by itself?

Tags: c

> bstsort.c

```
#include "header.h"

/*
    I had to write my own string functions. 
    checkString = returns 1 if the strings are the same, 0 otherwise 
    checkGreaterString = returns 1 if arg1 comes before arg2, 0 otherwise
 */

//insert a node
int insertNode(struct NODE *root, char *compare, int cFlag)
{
    // root node
     //printf("root -> input : %s\n", root -> input);

     //strings are the same
     if(checkString(root->input, compare, cFlag))
      {
          //printf("same string\n");
          root->isDuplicate++;  // count as duplicate 
          //printf("root input %s  and its duplicates is : %d\n", root->input, root->isDuplicate);
          return 0;
     }
     //strings are different
     else
     { 
         int check = checkGreaterString(root->input, compare, cFlag);
         //printf("check: %d\n", check);
         //compare comes before root
         if (check == 1)
         {
            // store compare at left node for root
            if(root -> left == NULL){   
                struct NODE *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(*tempNode));
                tempNode ->left = NULL;
                tempNode -> right = NULL;
                tempNode -> isDuplicate = 0;
                tempNode -> input = compare; //give node input
                root -> left = tempNode;     //set left node for root
                //printf("left node : %s\n", tempNode -> input);
                //printf("left node duplicate : %d\n", tempNode->isDuplicate); 
                //printf("left nodes parent %s\n", root -> input);
                return 0;
            }
            //left node is not empty, so insert node at that node 
            else
            {
                printf("root -> left -> input %s\n", root -> left -> input);
                printf("compare : %s\n", compare);
                insertNode(root -> left, compare, cFlag); 
                return 0;
            }
         }
         //compare comes after root
         else if(check == 0)
         {
            // store compare at right node for root
            if(root -> right == NULL){
                printf("im in the right node\n");
                struct NODE *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(*tempNode));
                tempNode ->left = NULL;
                tempNode -> right = NULL;
                tempNode -> isDuplicate = 0;
                tempNode -> input = compare;   //give node input
                root -> right = tempNode;     // set right node for root 
                //printf("right -> right -> input : %s\n", root -> right -> input);
                //printf("root -> left -> input %s\n", root -> left -> input);
                //printf("right node duplicate : %d\n", tempNode->isDuplicate); 
                //printf("right nodes parent %s\n", root -> input);
                return 0;

         }
         ////right node is not empty, so insert node at that node 
         else
             {  
                  //printf("im in the else for right node \n");
                  //printf("root->right->input%s\n", root -> right -> input);
                  insertNode(root -> right, compare, cFlag); 
             }
        }
    }
}
```

> header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct NODE {
    struct NODE *left;
    struct NODE *right;
    char *input;
    int isDuplicate;
};
struct NODE root;
```

I'm trying to make a binary tree, using the input given by the user. The input functions are in another file, but they all work properly. My problem is with the structs, or more precisely setting the left and right node of a struct. Everytime I set the left/right node of the root with a specific input, the input changes without me explicitly changing it. I think the problem is with my `tempNode` pointer, but I'm not exactly sure what is the issue and how to fix it.

Here is an example of the issue I spoke about above:

Let's say the user enters "for". "for" becomes the root of the tree

Then the user enters "ate". "ate" will become the left child of the root

**** up to here this works. if i print the strings for my root and left node of my root they will give me the correct string *******

Now, the user enters "test", "test" does become the right child of the root, but now when I print the left child it is also "test". the root string is still correct.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need two different string comparison functions `checkGreaterString` and `checkString`?

Comment: @babon My professor is making us do our own string functions.

Comment: but why two different functions to do the same job? How are the two functions different?

Comment: `checkString' is used to tell if the strings are the same. 'checkGreaterString' is used to tell which string comes first. This is just a requirement for the assignment, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
tempNode -> input = compare;
```

You let your node point to the input buffer, but that gets overwritten when you read the next input. (Except when you take extra precautions to avoid exactly that). Instead of copying the pointer, allocate memory to create a copy of the string, and let `tempNode -> input` point to that.